# How can i get that value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a program, but it's too big to spam it here, so I made a fiddle to illustrate my problem.

I need to catch and store in a variable the number `6`, but alert gives me `undefined` or `[object]`. Can you help me please?

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li class = "middle_item">
        <a>3</a>
        <a>6</a>
        <a>7</a>
    </li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
var aqui = $("li.middle_item").get("a:nth(2)"); 
alert(aqui);
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ufkoqeu8/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [.text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and [:eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) as below.

```
var aqui = $("li.middle_item a:eq(1)").text();
alert(aqui); // = 6
```

Demo@[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ufkoqeu8/1/)

Comment: What does de eq()? you have inserted 1 because the 1st a its = 0, the 2nd = 1 and 3rd = 2?

Comment: Yes, element index starts from 0

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var aqui = $("li.middle_item").find("a:nth(2)").text();
```